# Prove $f_n (x) := \frac{\sin (xn)}{n}$ is equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f_n (x) :=  \frac{\sin (xn)}{n}$. Prove the sequence is equicontinuous. So far I have [image]

Comment: Um... it seems like you're done.

Comment: So it is right? @NateEldredge

Comment: Yet again I run into a question which I see nothing wrong with, receiving multiple downvotes.  The user asked their question, and showed their attempt.  How unwelcoming can this "community" be?

Comment: Since you evidently know how to use $\LaTeX$, why not type out your proposed solution instead of asking people to read a blurry sideways photograph?  It's literally three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|f_n(x) - f_n(y) | = |\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} - \frac{\sin(ny)}{n}| < |n(x-y)/n| = |x-y|$. We select $\delta = \epsilon$ from here.